# Submit data from one controller to another controller model in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

Here i want to submit data from

```
 class Employee::GeneralInformationsController < ApplicationController
to class EmployeeRegistersController < ApplicationController
```

employee_register.rb model

Here i want to fetch all data from EmployeeRegister model in Employee::GeneralInformationsController
my controller of Employee::GeneralInformation is like this

```
class Employee::GeneralInformationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @employee_general_informations = EmployeeRegister.all
  end

  def show
    @employee_general_information = EmployeeRegister.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @employee_general_information = EmployeeRegister.new
  end

  def edit
    @employee_general_information = EmployeeRegister.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @employee_general_information = EmployeeRegister.new(params[:employee_general_information])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee_general_information.save
        format.html { redirect_to @employee_general_information, notice: 'General information was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render json: @employee_general_information, status: :created, location: @employee_general_information }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @employee_general_information.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @employee_general_information = EmployeeRegister.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee_general_information.update_attributes(params[:employee_general_information])
        format.html { redirect_to @employee_general_information, notice: 'General information was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @employee_general_information.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @employee_general_information = EmployeeRegister.find(params[:id])
    @employee_general_information.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to employee_general_informations_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

my form is like this

```
<%= simple_form_for(@employee_general_information) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Problem is after data is save from Employee::GeneralInformationsController  to EmployeeRegisters model it redirects to employee register show page. But it should redirect to  Employee::GeneralInformations show page. Where i am wrong?

Comment: Can you show your routes where `Employee::GeneralInformationsController` is mapped?

Comment: namespace :employee do resources :general_informations end

Comment: Hey @regmiprem gave you the answer 16 hours ago, hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

You are redirecting to @employee_general_information which is a EmployeeRegister model.... therefore it WILL go to EmployeeRegister#show...

If you want to redirect to another controller, use a route or a hash:

With the following route:

```
namespace :employee do
  resources :general_informations
end
```

Then:

```
redirect_to employee_general_information_path
```

or with Hash:

```
redirect_to :controller => 'employee/general_informations', :action => 'show'
```

Answer (score 2):

In your respond_to block try removing the @employee_general_information in format.html, like

```
def update
@employee_general_information = EmployeeRegister.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @employee_general_information.update_attributes(params[:employee_general_information])

    format.html ###goes to the default view for this action
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @employee_general_information.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: it redirect to employee_register when some data is created. hence what shoul be in create method..

Answer (score 2):

When you what to redirect to a specific controller in rails 3, you need to use named routes or a array to build the route, look:

```
# Here is the routes that you need
namespace :employee do
  resources :employee_registers, :controller => 'employee/general_informations'
end
```

So to solve your problem you need to replace all yours

```
redirect_to @employee_general_information
```

By

```
redirect_to [:employee, @employee_general_information]
```

this will redirect to `#show` action at `Employee::GeneralInformationsController`

One more thing, in your form you need to specify the controller to! If you use only `simple_form_for(@employee_general_information)` this form will send the data to `EmployeeRegistersController` because Rails map the class of the object to a controller with same name (`model EmployeeRegister` => `EmployeeRegistersController`).

To solve this you need to use this at your form

```
<%= simple_form_for([:employee, @employee_general_information]) do |f| %>
...
```

The final result should be:

```
# Employee::GeneralInformationsController
def create
  @employee_general_information = EmployeeRegister.new(params[:employee_general_information])

  if @employee_general_information.save
    redirect_to [:employee, @employee_general_information],
                notice: 'General information was successfully updated.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

And the form should be

```
<%= simple_form_for([:employee, @employee_general_information]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Read more about this at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: I changed as u tell in my simple form and it gives me error like   undefined method `employee_employee_registers_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004998e10>:0x000000037fe0b0>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= simple_form_for([:employee, @employee_general_information]) do |f| %>
2:   <%= f.error_notification %>
3: 
4:   <div class="form-inputs">

Comment: Uhh, reading the guides I find another problem, you cannot create a resources routes for a nonexistent model. You are using `resources :general_informations`, try to replace `namespace :employee do resources :general_informations` with `resources :employee_registers, :controller => 'employee/general_informations'`

Comment: can u edit in my question. I am messed up.. Thanks for your reply

Comment: It gives me Routes error.   Routing Error

uninitialized constant Employee::Employee

Comment: when i open localhost;3000/employee/general_informations then it give me routin error.. namespace :employee do resources :general_informations only do not give routin error.

Comment: You need to remove this `namespace :employee do resources :general_informations`, use only the routes that I specified at my answer

Comment: ya i did that and i get this error Routing Error uninitialized constant Employee::Employee

Answer (score 2):

Here it goes:

See your `Employee::GeneralInformationsController` carefully -

```
def create
    @employee_general_information = EmployeeRegister.new(params[:employee_general_information])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee_general_information.save
        format.html { redirect_to @employee_general_information, notice: 'General information was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render json: @employee_general_information, status: :created, location: @employee_general_information }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @employee_general_information.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is:

In the **create** method **after save**, you are redirecting to  `@employee_general_information` but this variable is pointing to the **EmployeeRegister** model and not your `Employee::GeneralInformationsController` and since after creation the default method calling in rails is `show` method of the pointing object so you are being redirected to the **EmployeeRegister's show**.

If you ask how it's pointing to that **EmployeeRegister** ?

The answer is:

Again see your first line defined in **create** method of **Employee::GeneralInformationsController**. Its `@employee_general_information = EmployeeRegister.new(params[:employee_general_information])`

In the above code, you are creating the parameters for `EmployeeRegister` model and then saving it to its corresponding table. By rails convention, the model to which you saves the data, the corresponding controller's **show** method is called by redirecting to it.
Hence the outcome.

**Solution:**

To redirect to the **Employee::GeneralInformationsController show method**, you have to explicitly define the root to the show method of the controller.

Check the path by running **rake routes**

However it's probably be like:

```
 redirect_to(employee_general_information_path(params[:employee_general_information]))
```